# electricity substation radiation measurements

Tags: high-voltage, radiation

I live next to an electricity substation and want to contact the operator/owner to ask for details about the station itself. What measurements should I ask them for?

Comment: which arrived first you or the substation?

Comment: the substation. it's council housing so not much I can do but want to understand information about it. is it kilovolt that i am after?

Comment: simply it's the current that produces the emf - so more current : stronger emf field. Not sure what shielding you could do? cover and earth bond the side of the property nearest the substation?

Comment: oh i'll build a pile if i need, trust me. what is the current measurement watt?

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing what you're trying to find out.

Comment: @user8921988: Judging from your question and comments it will be clear to the operator when you contact them that you have no idea what you are talking about. This also leads me to suspect that you think there is a hazard where none exists. Edit your question to (1) include a photo of the substation, (2) a photo of the high voltage warning label that shows the kV rating, (3) what country you are in and (4) what you are afraid of.

Comment: @user8921988 There are lots of studies you can reference. They will discuss the issues at various frequencies, tensions, and so on. Engineering studies will provide engineering results, which cannot be interpreted into biological impacts. That requires biological studies using measurement equipment and engineering support to interpret the measurements in order to help control their variables. At this level, there are far far fewer studies available. And the results vary. You can ask for measurements. But the problem is that you won't be able to interpret them for your purposes.

Comment: @user8921988 Most of my worries about substations (in my area) comes from when they explode. (Weather-related reasons, mostly -- we get ice/snow.) It's a very big explosion! I used to go out on Mock's Crest [cliff overseeing the city, about 200' above it] after a silver thaw, at about 2AM, and just watch power substations blow up over the next hour or so. Quite a show from there. Happened EVERY SINGLE TIME, too, that we got a silver thaw (about every 2 to 3 years back then.)

Comment: I'd do some measurements first, you probably get more electric and magnetic fields from the wiring in your walls than the substation, eliminate those first, then go after the substation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally EMI concerns come from high E fields which are designed to safe standards or restricted from housing ( in case of bad-weather related lines falling under HV transmission lines and generally used for free gardening land ( while gardeners generally dont work during tornado-like bad weather :)

The other minor nuisance is from arc noise from sub-optimal insulators.  The latter may be asily detected between channels on any AM radio.  If it sounds like a loud hum then you have something to complain about.